# .net mvc4 HttpPost null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, http-post

I have a problem while passing an object with HttpPost...
Once the form is submitted, the model is set "null" on the controller side, and I don't know where is the issue..

Here is my controller :

```
    public ActionResult AddUser(int id = 0)
    {
        Group group = db.Groups.Find(id);
        List<User> finalList = db.Users.ToList() ;

        return View(new AddUserTemplate()
            {
                group = group,
                users = finalList
            });
//Everything is fine here, the object is greatly submitted to the view
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUser(AddUserTemplate addusertemplate)
    {
//Everytime we get in, "addusertemplate" is NULL
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
//the model is null
        }
        return View(addusertemplate);

    }
```

Here is AddUserTemplate.cs :

```
    public class AddUserTemplate
{
    public Group group { get; set; }
    public User selectedUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the form which return a null value to the controller (note that the dropdown list is greatly populated with the good values) :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<fieldset>
    <legend>Add an user</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.group)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.users)
    <div class="editor-field">
//Here, we select an user from Model.users list
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedUser, new SelectList(Model.users))
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Could you add breakpoint to controller and watch what is in Request.Form variable? Show it please.

Comment: also, show that code for the `User` and `Group` classes

Comment: is the `addusertemplate` object null, or just its properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and in my case the `addusertemplate` model was not null, but its properties were all null.

That's because of a few model binding issues: `Html.HiddenFor` and `Html.DropDownListFor` do not work with complex types (such as `Group` or `User`) (at least that's how it is by default).

Also, `Html.HiddenFor` cannot handle collections.

Here's how to solve these issues:

- instead of `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.group)` there should be one `@Html.HiddenFor` for each property of the group that you need bound
- instead of `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.users)` you need to iterate through the list of users and for each object add `@Html.HiddenFor` for each property of the user that you need bound
- instead of `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedUser [...]`, create a property like `int SelectedUserId {get;set;}` and use that in the DropDownList (as it cannot handle complex types).

Here's the code that works:

**1.** The `User` and `Group` classes, as I imagined them to be:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**2.** The adjusted `AddUserTemplate` class:

```
public class AddUserTemplate
{
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public IList<User> Users { get; set; }

    public int SelectedUserId { get; set; }

    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get { return Users.Single(u => u.Id == SelectedUserId); }
    }
}
```

The adjustments:

- `Users` was changed from `ICollection` to `IList`, because we'll need to access elements by their indexes (see the view code)
- added `SelectedUserId` property, that will be used in the DropDownList
- the `SelectedUser` is not a readonly property, that returns the currently selected `User`.

**3.** The adjusted code for the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add an user</legend>

        @*Hidden elements for the group object*@
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Group.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Group.Name)

        @*Hidden elements for each user object in the users IList*@
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Users.Count; i++)
  {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Users[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Users[i].Name)
  }
        <div class="editor-field">
            @*Here, we select an user from Model.users list*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedUserId, new SelectList(Model.Users, "Id", "Name"))
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that does not require a bunch of hidden fields is to simply specify that you want the model passed to the controller. I think this is much cleaner.

```
@using(Html. BeginForm("action","controller", Model, FormMethod.Post)){
...
}
```